# Ho can I play encrypted video stream which is encrypted using "aes-encrypt-stream" in exo-player?

Tags: node.js, video, video-streaming, exoplayer

I am trying to create a video streaming server in NodeJS and an video streaming client in android using exo-player.

**My NodeJS server side code for video encryption is as follows:**

```js
app.get('/streamVideo/:fileName',(req, res)=>{
    try {
        var range = req.headers.range
        if(!range){
            range = "bytes=0_"
        }
        console.log(range)
        const videoPath = moviesDirMP4+"\\"+req.params.fileName
        const videoSize = fs.statSync(videoPath).size
        console.log(videoSize)
        const chunk = 5*1e6
        const start = Number(range.replace(/\D/g,""))
        const end = Math.min(start+chunk, videoSize-1)
        const contentLength = end - start + 1
        const headers = {
            "Content-Range": `bytes ${start}-${end}/${videoSize}`,
            "Accept_Ranges": "bytes",
            "Content-Length": contentLength,
            "Content-Type": "video/mkv"
        }
        console.log(`start: ${start}, end: ${end}, chunk: ${chunk}`)
        res.writeHead(206,headers)
        const stream = createEncryptStream(fs.createReadStream(videoPath, {start, end}))
        stream.pipe(res)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
})
```

I have a wrapper class for `Mediasource` and `DataSourceFactory`.

**`MediaSource` class:**

```java
@UnstableApi
public class EncryptedMediaSource implements DataSource {
    private final String key;
    private Uri uri;
    private CipherInputStream inputStream;

    public EncryptedMediaSource(String key){
        this.key = key;
    }
    @Override
    public void addTransferListener(TransferListener transferListener) {

    }

    @Override
    public long open(DataSpec dataSpec) throws IOException {
        this.uri = dataSpec.uri;
        try {
            File file = new File(Objects.requireNonNull(uri.getPath()));
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                inputStream = new CipherInputStream(new URL(uri.toString()).openStream(), cipher);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dataSpec.length;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Uri getUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        inputStream.close();
    }

    @Override
    public int read(@NonNull byte[] buffer, int offset, int length) throws IOException {
        if (length == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            if (inputStream!=null){
                return inputStream.read(buffer, offset, length);
            }
            else{
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**and `DataSourceFactory` class:**

```java
@UnstableApi
public class EncryptedDatasourceFactory implements DataSource.Factory {
    private final String key;

    public EncryptedDatasourceFactory(String key){
        this.key = key;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public DataSource createDataSource() {
        return new EncryptedMediaSource(key);
    }
}
```

**play video method:**

```java
try {
    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new EncryptedDatasourceFactory(Constants.AES_KEY);
    ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
    ExoPlayer player = new ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();
    binding.playerView.setPlayer(player);
    if (!videoURL.isEmpty()) {
        MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(videoURL);
        /*player.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
        player.prepare();
        player.play();*/
        MediaSource mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory).createMediaSource(mediaItem);
        player.setMediaSource(mediaSource);
        player.prepare();
        player.play();
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I am running the app I am getting Error:

```bash
Playback error
    androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
        at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleIoException(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:684)
        at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:654)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
    Caused by: androidx.media3.exoplayer.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, FlvExtractor, FlacExtractor, WavExtractor, AmrExtractor, PsExtractor, OggExtractor, TsExtractor, MatroskaExtractor, AdtsExtractor, Ac3Extractor, Ac4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AviExtractor, JpegExtractor) could read the stream.{contentIsMalformed=false, dataType=1}
        at androidx.media3.exoplayer.source.BundledExtractorsAdapter.init(BundledExtractorsAdapter.java:94)
        at androidx.media3.exoplayer.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1018)
        at androidx.media3.exoplayer.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:414)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```